# Does Republican Nikki Haley speak any Indian languages?

Tags: republican-party

According to [Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikki_Haley)

> Haley was born Nimarata Nikki Randhawa at Bamberg County Hospital in Bamberg, South Carolina,[1][2][10] to immigrant Sikh parents from Amritsar, Punjab, India.[11][12] Her father, Ajit Singh Randhawa, was a professor at Punjab Agricultural University,[13] and her mother, Raj Kaur Randhawa, received her law degree from the University of Delhi.[14]

She also claims, [*"I am the proud daughter of Indian American immigrants"*](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/GQQZnlnInKY) on the campaign trail. Since both of her parents presumably speak one of the languages native to India, likely Punjabi, does Nikki Haley herself also speak that language?

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6724). The comment section is not for extensive discussion on whether the question is asked in bad faith or not.

Answer (score 6):

I found the claim only addressed in this video, ['Would never disown my roots': Nikki Haley to NDTV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4qNMA7Vd7g)

> NH> I can't speak Punjabi. My parents tried to teach us when we were little.
>
> Interivewer> Can you understand it?
>
> NH> Very little.
>
> Interviewer> Your name Nikki means small in Punjabi.
>
> NH> I know what my name means. But other than that